# Static TabBar on all View controllers

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have 3 tab bar( Vc1 ,Vc2,Vc3) and theres a button on Vc2 from which it takes me to a signup page(which is not included in tab bar controller).Now I want to show those tabBar of those three View controllers(VC1,VC2,Vc3) on this signup page as well ...can anyone please help how do I get those tabs in signup as well ???
thanks in advance

Comment: You actually need a Container View in which on click on Vc2 signup View will be added as Subview

Comment: try checking https://github.com/RockinGarg/ContainerView-TabBar.git This can help you getting output , just flow is opposite to your requirement , I have added tab in container and you need to add a VC in containerView inside a Tabbar

Comment: is this solved ?

Comment: @iOSGeek thank you so much for your efforts...but my problem's bit different.Actually I'm trying to access that signup page from sideMenu and wanted those tab bars as well...so what I did I used a containerView  to make tab bars and added buttons to it and embedded that containerView to all those View controllers where I needed to show to those tabs

Comment: is this solved or should I do this for you ?, if solved you can close this Thread by accepting your answer too

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Different branch for your Expected output

**please check :** https://github.com/RockinGarg/ContainerView-TabBar.git

**Branch** - stack_Tab_Container

**clone** - git clone -b stack_Tab_Container https://github.com/RockinGarg/ContainerView-TabBar.git

Storyboard :

[image]

**Design Flow**

----> Tab Bar
  ---> VC1 -- Screen Designed in same ViewController
    ---> ------
  ---> VC2
    ---> SignUpVC

**Output**

[image]

on click of submit button of SignUp VC your passed details will be printed and you can perform your required tasks using that protocol I have used

**Update**

Code pushed in same repo as exactly you want - stack_Tab_Container

**Updated StoryBoard**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roafu.jpg)

@iosGeek I'm not sure if I did it the right way but working the way I wanted